# I want to extract numbers from string in a list

Tags: python, list, parsing

I have a list of lists like

```
 [['2 Cups Fresh breadcrumbs'], ['1/3 Cup Parmesan cheese, grated'], ['For frying  Vegetable Oil']]
```

I want to fetch the numbers from list elements like after fetching list should look like this

```
 [['2', 'Cups Fresh breadcrumbs'], ['1/3', 'Cup Parmesan cheese, grated'], ['','For frying  Vegetable Oil']]
```

I tried to parse numbers from string present in list.

Language - python

Comment: Are numbers always at the start?

Comment: yes always @bro-grammer

Comment: but in fraction also @bro-grammer

Comment: What are the expected number formats? Obviously data are coming from  recipes, so no scientific notation like `3.7e-10`, I assume. But what about `3-5 eggs` or `0.5 l` or `4 (6 ounce)` or `2 1/2 cups`?

Comment: yes we have to extract only number part like if (50 gm oil) then it will be extracted like ('50', 'gm oil')

Comment: Ah, a homework question without attempt. Please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `re` module with this pattern:

```
data = [['2 Cups Fresh breadcrumbs'], ['1/3 Cup Parmesan cheese, grated'], ['For frying  Vegetable Oil']]
pattern = '([0-9].*?)?\s(.*)'
[[item for found in re.findall(pattern, i[0]) for item in found] for i in data]
#[['2', 'Cups Fresh breadcrumbs'], ['1/3', 'Cup Parmesan cheese, grated'], ['','For frying  Vegetable Oil']]
```

Comment: You have a typo in the second `pattern`

Comment: @FHTMitchell Thanks bro!

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach would be to flatten the list and check if each element startswith a digit

```
>>> import itertools 

>>> l =  [['2 Cups Fresh breadcrumbs'], ['1/3 Cup Parmesan cheese, grated'], ['For frying  Vegetable Oil']]
>>> [a.split(maxsplit=1) if a[0].isdigit() else ['', a]for a in itertools.chain(*l)]
>>> [['2', 'Cups Fresh breadcrumbs'], ['1/3', 'Cup Parmesan cheese, grated'], ['', 'For frying  Vegetable Oil']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use -

```
import re
a=[['2 Cups Fresh breadcrumbs'], ['1/3 Cup Parmesan cheese, grated'], ['For frying  Vegetable Oil']]
pattern = re.compile("^([0-9]+)+$")

b=[]
for words in a:
    w_lst = words[0].split()
    b.append([ [w_lst[0], ' '.join(w_lst[1:]) ] if re.search(r'\d', w_lst[0]) else words for word in words][0])
print(b)
```

**Output**

```
[['2', 'Cups Fresh breadcrumbs'], ['1/3', 'Cup Parmesan cheese, grated'], ['For frying  Vegetable Oil']]
```

**Explanation**

`a` is your original list. `b` will be the final output.

`w_lst = words[0].split()` takes each string in your nested list and splits the string into a list of words.

`re.search(r'\d', w_lst[0])` searches for digits in your first word. This regex can be modified to accommodate stricter rules for detecting numbers in your strings. Returns `True` if found.

Use that in an if-else condition, you output the original string if this condition does not satisfy.

If it does, `[w_lst[0], ' '.join(w_lst[1:])]` is outputted. This the the first word as the first element of a list, followed by all other words joined back as a single string.

Hope this helps!